# Best practice to integrate Azure Data Factory and Slack?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, slack

I have Azure Data Factory Pipeline and I would like to send notification to Slack in the end of pipeline. Notification body is formed from content of database data.

Best practice to integrate Azure Data Factory and Slack?

A) ADF Webbook(to slack) -> Slack
B) ADF Web -> Logic Apps Web+Webhook -> Slack

Comment: check this http://www.nibrasmanna.com/forwarding-azure-infrastructure-alerts-to-slack/ is it helphul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is one way that worked for me
Firstly I have taken 2 variables

1. ListOfFiles - Array
2. strListOfFiles - string

Here is the pipeline that Im using:

[image]

**`ForEach`** loop Activities:

[image]

I have made items in my settings to read the child items i.e..

```
@activity('Get List of Files').output.childitems
```

Then in the **`set variables`** I'm storing all the arrays of `ListOfFiles` inside `strListOfFiles`

[image]

And then in the **`Web`** Im using my Logic App URL making post method having `{ "ListOfFiles":@{variables('strListOfFiles')} }` inside the body.

[image]

**Logic App workflow**

[image]

Im using the below JSON Schema inside the HTTP request

```
{
    "properties": {
        "ListOfFiles": {
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Comment: what should be done on slack end or how to allow incoming messages be allowed?

Comment: what is slack URL here?